# Nativescript Stuck and Stop when do http request/axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i have code to do login in nativescript with vue js. This my code

```
login2: function(){
    this.isLoading = 'true';
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var q = this;
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            q.isLoading = 'false';
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(param);
  },
```

If i click mybutton (call login() function), it will stuck (keep loading) if i try to do login 5 times. Anybody can solve this problem?

Comment: the declaration is 
login: function(){

Comment: What is `http` here? Is it axios or http module?

Comment: in this code http module. But with axios get the same problem

Comment: I have used axios, I can confirm it works. At same time that's not how http module should be used, refer [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) to know how the default http module is used. You seem to be following syntax of `XMLHttpRequest` request, which should also work as long its pointed to right module. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Why don't use fetch instead?

Comment: @Steven Internally everything uses the same Http module, just the syntax is different.